# Change color of react-big-calendar events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar

I need to make a calendar with events and I decided to use [react-big-calendar](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html). But I need to make events of different colors. So each event will have some category and each category has corresponding color. How can I change the color of the event with react? [image: react-big-calendar same color example]

Result should look something like this [image: react-big-calendar different colors example]

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Sorry, I haven't read the documentation really well. It can be done with the help of `eventPropGetter` attribute. I've made it like this:

```
eventStyleGetter: function(event, start, end, isSelected) {
    console.log(event);
    var backgroundColor = '#' + event.hexColor;
    var style = {
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        borderRadius: '0px',
        opacity: 0.8,
        color: 'black',
        border: '0px',
        display: 'block'
    };
    return {
        style: style
    };
},

render: function () {

    return (
        <Layout active="plan" title="Planning">
            <div className="content-app fixed-header">
                <div className="app-body">
                    <div className="box">
                        <BigCalendar
                            events={this.events}
                            defaultDate={new Date()}
                            defaultView='week'
                            views={[]}
                            onSelectSlot={(this.slotSelected)}
                            onSelectEvent={(this.eventSelected)}
                            eventPropGetter={(this.eventStyleGetter)}
                            />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

Comment: How to drag and drop external events in react-big-calendar ? Does it have support for drag & drops ?

Comment: [here](https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar/issues/15) is the open issue in [react-big-calendar](https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar). Seems to have a solution that is not yet merge

Answer (score 19):

Additional tip on how to style different kinds of events: In the `myEvents` array of event objects, I gave each object a boolean property `isMine`, then I defined:

```js
<BigCalendar

  // other props here

  eventPropGetter={
    (event, start, end, isSelected) => {
      let newStyle = {
        backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
        color: 'black',
        borderRadius: "0px",
        border: "none"
      };

      if (event.isMine){
        newStyle.backgroundColor = "lightgreen"
      }

      return {
        className: "",
        style: newStyle
      };
    }
  }
/>
```

Answer (score 6):

**This solution is simple !**

```
eventPropGetter={(event) => {
  const backgroundColor = event.allday ? 'yellow' : 'blue';
  return { style: { backgroundColor } }
}}
```

change the condition according to your need and it is done.

Comment: worked at `"@mirror/react-big-calendar": "^0.22.1"`

Answer (score 3):

Siva Surya's solution is the fastest, and I have added the color property as well. Thanks...

```
import React, {useEffect, useLayoutEffect} from 'react';
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer,globalizeLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar'
import moment from 'moment';
import { connect } from 'frontity';
import BackgroundWrapper from 'react-big-calendar/lib/BackgroundWrapper';

const MyCalendar = ({ actions, state, objetoBloque, formato }) => {

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);
const myEventsList = [
  {
    title: 'My Event',
    start: '2022-06-21T13:45:00-05:00',
    end: '2022-06-25T14:00:00-05:00',
    // elcolor:'red'
    colorEvento:'red'
  },
  {
    title: 'Otro',
    start: '2022-06-15T13:45:00-05:00',
    end: '2022-06-23T14:00:00-05:00',
    colorEvento:'green',
    color:'white'
  }
];
    return(
        <div>
        <Calendar
        // defaultDate = {defaultDate}
          localizer={localizer}
          events={myEventsList}
          startAccessor="start"
          endAccessor="end"
          style={{ height: 500 }}
          BackgroundWrapper = "red"
          eventPropGetter={(myEventsList) => {
            const backgroundColor = myEventsList.colorEvento ? myEventsList.colorEvento : 'blue';
            const color = myEventsList.color ? myEventsList.color : 'blue';
            return { style: { backgroundColor ,color} }
          }}
          
        />
      </div>

    )

}
export default connect(MyCalendar);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Searching for how to change the border colour of an event also lead me here, and I couldn't find the answer anywhere else, but found that adding the following done the trick:

```
border: "black",
borderStyle: "solid"
```